# App claims it's open, refuses to close

Tags: mac, applications

I am trying to remove an App that is called "Live Chat" but when I go to Applications > Live Chat and select move to trash, it says that the program is open even though it is not and doesn't allow me to remove it.

Thanks!

Comment: Does the problem persist after a reboot?

Comment: You can try running `killall -9 "Live Chat"`

Comment: Is https://www.livechat.com/app/ the application?

Answer (score 3):

You can remove most apps when they are not running, so move the app to the trash and then log out of your Mac from the Apple menu - Log out...

When you log back in, the app won’t start since it’s in the Trash and then you can empty it.

As long as it’s a normal app and not one that installed helpers, start at boot, or malware this works for all basic apps. Non-basic apps or ones that run hidden helpers like most Adobe products, Zoom, backup and remote control software need to be uninstalled or deactivated based on how they were implemented.

[Live Chat](https://www.livechat.com/app/) may need an uninstall...

> ... start automatically when you turn on your computer, so you never miss a chat.

If you struggle, the steps to isolate malware and persistent apps might need a follow on question based on how your mac is set up, and the specific of the exact app you have.

Answer (score 2):

You should run the activity monitor (from Launchpad, open the folder named `Other` to find it) and see if there is an app called Live Chat which is maybe running in the background.

If you find the app in Activity Monitor double click on it and you'll be given an option to force quit the app. After that you should be able to remove app.  When you run activity monitor be sure the CPU tab near the top is selected.